# How to do an ocean wave?

Tags: materials, node-editor, ocean-simulation

Im trying to implement a 3d wave similar to this 2d image.

[image]

My main struggle is the white splash from the wave, more specifically the material node.

Comment: I'm looking forward for an answers (or your solution) for such thing. I don't have a clue, but people here will ask you if it is still image or animation, 2D / 3D, etc ... so please add as much details as possible to let people here better and quickly understand to your goals in context. Thank you